# Apex: "Can't declare public getter on private property"

Tags: apex

I want to create a `public` getter and `private` setter for `private` property. How to do that using **shorthand** (not Java-like separate methods at the bottom of class)?

Here's what I'm trying to do (not working, getting "Can't declare public getter on private property"):

```
private Decimal number { public get; set; }
```

Comment: Just curious, if you want to make read and write access to the property public, why does the property still need to be kept private?

Comment: I formed my question not very well, sorry. I wanted private setter and public getter

Comment: Ah ok, I've added my answer then.

Comment: You should also consider clarifying your question for future readers.

Comment: I edited my post and will focus more on clarifying questions in the future. Thanks a lot for great answer!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want a private setter and public getter define your property like so...

```
public Decimal myNumber { get; private set; }
```

You can read more about Apex Properties and access modifiers [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_properties.htm).

Comment: Or, stated generically, the access modifier of the variable must be the greater of the access modifiers for the accessor and mutator.